# Why the URL to retrieve data from is not returning JSON data, but rather an HTML page with a "Resource not found" error message?

Tags: python

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_fut = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=nifty_bank_fut'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
response = requests.get(url_fut, headers=headers)
data_fut = response.json()\['data'\]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_fut)

print(df)
```

For Above code i am getting the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value]
```

Comment: Because the url isn't valid and the data you're looking for doesn't exist or is somewhere else.

Comment: But if you paste the URL in the browser it is returning the data

Comment: I can't replicate that, I get a "resource not found" page when I paste the URL. To clarify we are talking about "https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=nifty_bank_fut" right?

Comment: I am able to replicate that again you need to go to "https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=nifty_bank_fut". I think you nedd to visit nseindia.com website first and the look for futures contract. and then you will have the in it.